# SSL securing site on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl

How can I make sure that users cannot access http address on google appengine at all? Now usesrs can use https or http to access site, but is there any way to force users using http protocol to https url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok now I found a way to do it, add following element to your web.xml, and your xml should have following xml definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs

Comment: Please append this information to your Original Post and remove this one.

Comment: @RobertPitt newbie is correct - this is an answer, so it should be posted as one, regardless of who provided it.